# Bind Vue on body or others element

Tags: vue.js

I've seen many times Vue instance is bind on `body` tag.
Other times this is bind on a `div id`

I'm asking when i should use `body` tag or an `id` tag (that limit the scope of the Vue instance).

Two examples:

```
new Vue({
  el: 'body'
});
```

OR

```
new Vue({
  el: '#a-div'
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should never use the `body` tag. In fact, it raises a warning to use the `body` tag.

> Added a warning when mounting the root instance to body or html. This is no longer recommended in 2.0.

This is from the [release notes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.3), anyways it's incorrect, it raises an error.

Comment: i need to dynamically change body element's class from vue data, how to bind class on body tag??

Comment: @გიორგი you can still use vanilla Javascript, just add a watcher and use the `classList` DOM API to add/remove classes on the `body` tag.

Comment: Is there the best way to bind a navbar and the main container?

Comment: Some explanation of *why* would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct: **binding the main Vue instance on `body` element is really not recommended!**

For more information:

- [Why it's not recommended to render to `<body>` element](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375#61b8) (related to React, but similar principle applies to Vue too)

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: According to the [v2 docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el): "The provided element merely serves as a mounting point. Unlike in Vue 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance to <html> or <body>."