# v-on:submit.prevent not stopping form submission

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm quite new to Vue and this will be my second dummy project in efforts to learn more about it.

I currently have a form and I am trying to prevent form submission, according to the docs I can do this with `v-on:submit.prevent`.

I have added this into my form tag, but when submitting the form it is still going through and is not being prevented at all.

I am using Vue version 2.1.3 and below is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Node JS Server</title>
</head>
<body id="chat">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
        <input>
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.6.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var socket = io();

        new Vue({
            el: '#chat',

            methods: {
                send: function(e) {

                    alert('Send method!');

                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can see from the docs, the form should not submit.

**Edit**

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xje4r1u8/1/) with the code in it

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console?

Comment: @Soviut No errors in the console.

Comment: Related to [Bind Vue on body or others element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164791/bind-vue-on-body-or-others-element)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xje4r1u8/2/

You need to make following changes in HTML:

```
<div id="chat">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="send">
       <input>
       <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

in your HTML, you had `<body id="chat">` which was causing problem, replacing this with `div` solved the problem.

Comment: Could you kindly explain what is the relation between a body and the form submission event handler?

Comment: Vue was failing to mount because it does not want `body` used as the root element. So the event handler was never actually assigned. [See docs note for `el`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el).

Answer (score 8):

This is a strange, but standard-compliant behaviour: If a form only contains one input, it will *always* submit, and `preventDefault()` will *not* prevent that.

See here: [Why does a FORM with one text INPUT submit on enter while one with two text INPUTs does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797025/why-does-a-form-with-one-text-input-submit-on-enter-while-one-with-two-text-inpu)

Solution: add annother input with `type="hidden"`

Comment: A very late comment, but this answer was one of the first googling the problem: this solved my problem. However a input type="hidden" didn't work for me, I'd add a normal input with display:none and that solved the question