# Vue.js + Call the click event for whole page document

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

With **JQuery**, click event of the any item in the page can be captured as below.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
     // event.target is the clicked element object
});
```

How to do the same with **Vue.js**?

Comment: [`document.addEventListener('click', event => { ... }, false)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Thanks. But i want to know how to do it by Vue.js

Comment: What do you mean? `Vue.js` is just JavaScript and I'm pretty sure you can't mount a `Vue` instance on the `document`; it can only be mounted on an element

Comment: If it's a Vue "single page app", then just put an `@click` in the highest element you can (usually whatever is right after `<body>`), as per @Marek's answer. If it's a web page with a mix-of-Vue-and-other-stuff and you want to capture clicks on the entire page... then you need a classic JS click listener, as well then it's no longer a Vue topic at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create div as top node, right after `<body>`
2. Make it main container and mount VueJS on it.
3. `<div id='yourMainDiv' @click='yourClickHandler'>`
4. In your VueJS `<script>` part use it:

```
methods: {
  yourClickHandler(event) {
    // event.target is the clicked element object
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of wrapping the content in a div, cannot we use the body element?   <body  @click='yourClickHandler'>

Comment: not sure about that, never done it, but maybe can work

Comment: You cannot bind Vue to the body element (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164791/bind-vue-on-body-or-others-element)) and therefore not provide a template containing a body-tag.

Answer (score 32):

The [answer provided by M U](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41952558/2483911) is correct and works.

Yet if you don't like messing with your template (e.g. not put a lot of event handlers in it) or your Vue app is only a small part of a bigger application, it's also perfectly fine and acceptable to register event handlers manually.

To add global event handlers in your script *the Vue way* you should register them in the [mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and remove them in the [beforeDestroy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) hooks.

Short example:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function () {
    // Attach event listener to the root vue element
    this.$el.addEventListener('click', this.onClick)
    // Or if you want to affect everything
    // document.addEventListener('click', this.onClick)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
    this.$el.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick)
    // document.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick)
  },
  methods: {
    onClick: function (ev) {
      console.log(ev.offsetX, ev.offsetY)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 25):

All of the answers provided works, but none of them mimic the real behavior of `$(document).click()`. They catch just clicks on the root application element, but not on the whole document. Of course you can set your root element to `height: 100%` or something. But in case you want to be sure, it's better to modify [Bengt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483911/bengt) solution and attach event listener directly to **document**.

```
new Vue({
  ...
  methods: {
    onClick() {},
  }
  mounted() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.onClick);
  },
  ...
});
```

Remember you need to use **@click.stop** in children elements if you for some reason need to stop event propagation to the main handler.

Comment: Kudos to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) for already solving this in question comments.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you need to track click event outside of specific element, you 
can use [vue-clickaway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clickaway) component. Example from the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/simplesmiler/4w1cs8u3/):

```
<div id="demo">
  <p v-on-clickaway="away" @click="click" :style="{ color: color }">{{ text }}</p>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  mixins: [VueClickaway.mixin],
  data: {
    text: 'Click somewhere.',
    color: 'black',
  },
  methods: {
    click: function() {
      this.text = 'You clicked on me!';
      this.color = 'green';
    },
    away: function() {
      this.text = 'You clicked away...';
      this.color = 'red';
    },
  },
});
```