# Vue.js global event handling

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a vue.js 2 web app. When some specific global event fires, I want to notify user with some nice dialog. Specifically, I want to notify user, when a new version of service worker is found.

So, in my main.js I have:

```js
reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
   //this is where I want to show an info dialog
})
...
//and this is where I start up my Vue app instance
new Vue({el: '#app', render: h => h(App), vuetify, router })
```

**The problem is, how do I tell a Vue component to do something from global scope?**

My first suggestion was to define a global vue variable Vue.prototype.$showSwCautionDialog = false and then try to change it somehow from the global scope, but it didnt' work.
I read something about global event bus, but not really sure that that's my case.

Comment: You can set it using store or using `$root`. However I don't recomment using `$root`.

Comment: Your can do so, following this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41958386/11266880