# Where to mount Vuejs keeping HTML5 structure right?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

From official Vuejs documentation, about mounting point:

> The provided element merely serves as a mounting point. Unlike in Vue 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance to **html** or **body**

What if I have page structured like this:
*(I omitting HTML,HEAD tags here)*

```
<body>
  <!-- <div class="wrapper"> It just doesn't feel right -->
  <header>  
     <!-- Header content, NAV, etc. -->
  </header>
  <div role="main">
    <!-- Page content -->
  </div>
  <footer>
    <!-- Footer content -->
  </footer>
  <!-- </div>-->
</body>
```

I really don't want to add wrapper inside **body** because I'd like to have my HTML structured according recommendations. At the same time I'd like to use only one instance of Vue application.

What is the best technique in this case?

Comment: What W3C recommendations forbid the use of a wrapper div?

Comment: @ceejayoz Well, you just have encouraged me to use it (the wrapper) & forget it. There are a lot of articles by CSS gurus, fighting for "html semantic purity", so I am a bit confused with this one

Comment: It's standard for single page apps to be initialized with a single, root node.

Answer (score 1):

You use to be able to add an id to the body tag and use that, but apparently that wasn't pure enough either. How you have it is how I do it and I believe it is the recommended way. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164791/bind-vue-on-body-or-others-element) and [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.3). It is a fun exercise to strive for purity but in the wild it is hard to attain.

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper" id="app">
  <header>  
     <!-- Header content, NAV, etc. -->
  </header>
  <div role="main">
    <!-- Page content -->
  </div>
  <footer>
    <!-- Footer content -->
  </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```