# Logo in header is not visible when Vue.js id is applied to the body

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on converting landing page templates from Angular.js to Vue.js (v. 3) and am encountering an issue with the script being applied to the entire body versus just a specific element.

When I apply id="awApp" to the body, my logo image does not render. It is there in dev tools, but is not visible in the browser. If I move id="awApp" down to , the script then excludes the header and the logo is visible.
I am needing the script to be able to work across the entire page, but am not sure where I am going wrong.
My script as of now is a super simple function to determine the current year for copyrights.

**Please note: Vue.js v.3 and Vue.js in general is new to me. I'm a react.js gal that has found herself in a position requiring Vue.js. Any help is truly appreciated!

Please see the code snippet below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="MindFire Agency" />

    <link rel="icon" href="##URL_FAV_ICON##" />
    <title>Mindfire Agency</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <style>
      main > .container {
        padding: 60px 15px 0;
      }

      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body id="awApp" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <header>
      <!-- FIXED NAVBAR AND/OR HEADER -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand"><img
            src="http://www.mindfire.agency/static/images/mindfire-agency-logo.png"
            alt="logo"
            width="120px;"
          /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- / HEADER/NAVBAR -->

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <main  role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5 gx-5">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <img
            src="http://placehold.it/1200x400"
            alt="hero image"
            class="img-fluid"
          />
          <h2 class="mt-3">Headline goes here...</h2>
          <p>##firstname##,</p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis
            dolore eaque, facere id molestias perspiciatis sit? Accusantium
            aspernatur delectus eius fuga id modi non, obcaecati perferendis
            quia, quidem quos repellendus.
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>benefit 1</li>
            <li>benefit 2</li>
            <li>benefit 3</li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid
            assumenda consectetur deleniti est ipsam nemo nobis officiis quasi,
            quod! Ad illum labore laudantium nemo, nesciunt nisi porro
            recusandae repellat.
          </p>
          <p class="lead">Call to action</p>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="card shadow p-3">
              <!--<img class="card-img-top rz-card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/400x100" alt="Card image cap">-->
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Call to action</h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
                <form method="post">
                  <div class="row mb-3 gx-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label class="form-label"
                        >First Name <span>*</span></label
                      >
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="firstname"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##firstname##"
                        required
                      />
                      <small
                        class="form-text"
                        >This field is required.</small
                      >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label class="form-label"
                        >Last Name <span>*</span></label
                      >
                      <input
                        type="text"                      
                        name="lastname"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##lastname##"
                        required
                      />
                      <small
                        class="form-text"
                        >This field is required.</small
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <label class="form-label"
                        >Email Address <span>*</span></label
                      >
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="email"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##email##"
                        required
                      />
                      <small
                        class="form-text"
                        >This field is required.</small
                      >
                      <small
                        class="form-text"
                        >Doesn't look like a valid email address!</small
                      >
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <label class="form-label">Phone </label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="phone"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##phone##"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <label class="form-label">Street Address </label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="address1"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##address##"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="row mb-3 gx-2">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label class="form-label">City</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="city"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##city##"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <label class="form-label">State</label>
                      <select
                        name="state"
                        class="form-select"
                      >
                        <option value="##state##" selected="selected">##state##</option>
                        <option
                          value="state"
                        >
                          state
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label class="form-label">Zip Code</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="zip"
                        class="form-control"
                        value="##zip##"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <div class="row mb-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value=""/>
                        <label class="form-check-label">Check me out</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
  
                  <!-- PURL specific hidden inputs here -->
                  <input
                    type="hidden"
                    name=""
                    value=""
                  />
                  <!-- /PURL specific hidden inputs here -->
  
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                  
                  <div><small class="form-text text-muted">
                    <em
                      >* Denotes a required field. <br />
                      Answer all required fields to submit the form.</em
                    >
                  </small></div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <!-- /MAIN CONTENT -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">&copy; {{currentYear}} |
          <a href="##URL_PRIVACY##">Privacy Policy</a> |
          <a href="##URL_LEGAL##">Legal</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /FOOTER -->

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!-- /BOOTSTRAP JS -->

    <!-- VUE APP CODE -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
    <script>
      const Main = {
        data() {
          return {
            currentYear: new Date().getFullYear()
          }
        }
      }

      Vue.createApp(Main).mount('#awApp')
    </script>
    <!-- /VUE APP CODE-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your Vue script is inside of your template which throws an error.
2. You [shouldn't bind to body in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39166186/3931488).
3. With Vue, img src needs to be bound. The shorthand is `:src`
4. The `width` property on the HTML img tag shouldn't use px. Not quite the same as CSS width.

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <style>
    main>.container {
      padding: 60px 15px 0;
    }
    
    .bd-placeholder-img {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
</head>


<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100 ">

  <div id="app">
    <h2>test</h2>

    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img :src="imgSrc" alt="logo" width="120" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


<script>
  const app = Vue.createApp({
    // instead of mount, u could use this: // el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        currentYear: new Date().getFullYear(),
        imgSrc: 'https://www.mindfire.agency/static/images/mindfire-agency-logo.png'
      }
    }
  })

  app.mount('#app')
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @JohnVandivier! This was clear, concise and easy-to-follow. Really informative too!